# How can I make colcon output a plain CMake project's output with the ninja generator?

Tags: cmake, build, ninja, colcon

[Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) redirects the `stderr` output to `stdout`. When used with [colcon](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/index.html) and its [colcon-cmake](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-cmake) extension, the error log is therefore not displayed when a ninja package build is failing.

How can I see the build error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct solution to the problem (see [Colcon does not show failed build output if using Ninja generator](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-cmake/issues/67)).

This GitHub issue mentions a [workaround](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-cmake/issues/67#issuecomment-1104434793), though: Add `--event-handlers console_cohesion+` to the `colcon build` call, either systematically, or only on a build failure, depending on how clean you want your build output to be. It reveals the stdout output (and thus the errors issued by ninja).